# UIAlertview is called multiple times

Tags: xcode, uialertview

I have the following code in my application. On a view controller I have two UIButton controls that each do different operations. When I press the first button I have a UIAlertView to confirm the operation. This works fine. I setup the second button the same way. When I press the second button the first UIAlertView appears briefly, and then the second UIAlertView appears. It works okay at that point but then the first UIAlertView appears again.

If I take out the UIAlertViews completely and just update a label on the view to indicate which button was pressed I don't get either button called a second time so I have isolated this to the inclusion of the UIAlertViews.

Can anyone point to something in my code that is causing this? Here's the code.

```
- (IBAction)clearInspectionsClicked {

    UIAlertView *alertClear = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Please Confirm" 
                                            message:@"Clear out all inspection data?" 
                                            delegate:self 
                                            cancelButtonTitle:@"Clear" 
                                            otherButtonTitles:@"Cancel", nil];
[alertClear show];

}

- (IBAction)loadSampleDataClicked {

    UIAlertView *alertLoad = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Please Confirm" 
                                                    message:@"Load Sample data?" 
                                                   delegate:self 
                                          cancelButtonTitle:@"Load" 
                                          otherButtonTitles:@"Cancel", nil];
    [alertLoad show];
}


-(void) alertView:(UIAlertView*)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
{
    NSString *title = [alertView buttonTitleAtIndex:buttonIndex];
    if ([title isEqualToString:@"Clear"])
    {
        [self clearInspections];
        [self.StatusLabel setText:@"Inspection data has been cleared!"];
    }
    if ([title isEqualToString:@"Load"])
    {
        [self loadSampleData];
        [self.StatusLabel setText:@"Sample data has been loaded!"];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Is it possible that you have one of the buttons wired to two of those actions? it is possible to wire multiple actions to one given control in Interface Builder, and it would cause this exact behavior.

Comment: If I take out the UIAlertViews and instead just display a status message in a label on the view, only one action is called. However, I will check through the debugger to confirm this. Thanks for the post!

Comment: That was it! Thanks for pointing that out. After looking at the actions I noticed that the second button was wired to both. I deleted the erroneous action link and now it works fine. Sometimes the solution is simpler than you think!! Thanks again!